# AS3 - Passing a function with variable through a timer

Tags: function, actionscript-3, timer

basically, I have a function called setEnemies, it spawns the number of enemies I decide like this:

```
public function Main()
{
setEnemies(3);          
}
```

Here's the setEnemies:

```
private function setEnemies(numbers:Number):void
{
        for (var i:int = 0; numbers > i; i++)
        {
        _Enemy = new Enemy(_player.x, _player.y);       
        addChild(_Enemy);
        addChild(_Enemy.rocket); // add enemy rocket to stage   
        _Enemy.isAlive = true;
        enemies.push(_Enemy);

        }

}
```

So far it works.

Well, when the enemy dies I want the game to wait for 1 sec and then spawn 1 more Enemy, like this:

```
var spawnTimer:Timer; // Spawn enemy timer.
spawnTimer = new Timer(1000, 1); 
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, setEnemies(1));
spawnTimer.start();
```

But I get the following error:

"Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type Function.
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, setEnemies(1));"

Why does it behave like that? and sure, I can probably find another method for it to wait a second and spawn, but this way seems to me the most natural way.
Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, setEnemies(1));
```

I believe the issues is the second argument of addEventListener. That function is looking for an event to listen to ( TimerEvent.TIMER ) and a function. You passed in setEnemies(1) which will call the function and then pass in whatever that function returns as the second argument -- not the actual function itself.

I think what you want to do is:

```
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void{
    setEnemies(1);
});
```

This creates and passes in an anonymous function for the event to fire.

Also if just for future reference if you want to pass in a function you have already made you either have to wrap it a function like I did above or type in just the name such as:

```
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, setEnemies);
```

By omitting the () and arguments you pass in the reference to the function.

Comment: It works bro, though I get a weird warning:  Warning: return value for function 'anonymous' has no type declaration.

Comment: Try putting ": void" after the () for the anonymous function.

Comment: You also need an event argument: `function(e:TimerEvent):void { }`

Comment: that's all incorrect, first he's calling a method instead of passing a reference to it, second a listener must have the event parameter correctly set.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include event paramter. I'm not sure what you are getting at with the reference bit. Is that somehow different from what I explained in middle part of my answer?